# How can I read the docstring/help of a python module from cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-arguments, manual

Consider that you are in the Windows command prompt or similar command line environment. How can you get info about a Python module from its docstring printed to the console?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you will want to load the module without executing it, which could have side effects. This is supported by Python’s `ast` module, which even has a helper for getting docstrings. Try this:

```
python3 -c"import ast, sys; a = ast.parse(open(sys.argv[1]).read()); print(ast.get_docstring(a))" "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

### **The Shortut (Hack)**

Generally (in 2.7):

```
python -c"print 'Hello world'"
```

(in 3.x):

```
python -c"print('Hello world')"
```

will output: `Hello world`

But if you pass `-c` as an argument into a module, something else happens.

For an example, navigate to `[your Python folder]\Tools\Scripts`. If your script does not take parameter `-c`, a shortcut is simply to run:

```
python reindent.py -c
```

This will result in an error for the argument: "-c not recognized", but it will also return the docstring to the console. (One limitation is that the output cannot be routed to the clipboard using `|clip`.)

Generally, if your script `myscript.py` contains a docstring and expects no argument `-c`:

```
python myscript.py -c
```

returns

```
option -c not recognized
[__docstring__]
```

## The Works

Once you are in the folder of `reindent.py` you can get an error-free docstring:

```
python -c"import reindent; print reindent.__doc__"
```

For producing a browsable help text, which prints both the docstring and lists the containing classes, functions, and global variables, use:

```
python -c"import reindent; help(reindent)"
```

To output to the clipboard only (Warning: Contents will be replaced!):

```
python -c"import reindent; help(reindent)"|clip
```

### Deeper

Now that you have figured out what classes and functions are accessible (see above), you can retrieve the methods of a class and inner docstrings:

```
python -c"from reindent import Reindenter; help(Reindenter)"
```

Comment: This answer strikes me as very dangerous, since all of these options execute the full script — which could have unpredictable consequences including the permanent loss of data. (What if the script ignores its options and is a cleanup script that deletes files, for example.) Also: the `-c` trick won’t work if the script takes a `-c` option; and what of `-c` means “clean” and deletes files; and, it won’t print the docstring, it would print the `argparse` documentation, which are often quite different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean print interactively, just start python without any arguments to get a REPL (read–eval–print loop).

```
python
import mypackage
help(mypackage)
dir(mypackage)
```

executed one after another and so forth.

If you mean programmatically, see @noumenal's answer.